# Conservation Equations Used in Boltzmann Transport Equation: Kardar

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conservation-laws, boltzmann-equation

I am reading through the derivation of the Boltzmann transport equation in the text, Statistical Mechanics of Particles by Kardar. I am unable to make sense of the conservation equations described.

There are two particles, before a collision at $\vec{p}_{1}$, $\vec{p}_{2}$. After collision, they transform $\vec{p'}_{1}$, $\vec{p'}_{2}$. Now the text says to consider the relative momenta for a moment.
$$\vec{p}=\vec{p}_{1}-\vec{p}_{2}$$
$$\vec{p'}=\vec{p'}_{1}-\vec{p'}_{2}$$

it then says that in elastic collisions , the magnitude of $\vec{p}$ is preserved.  This is already confusing me because the two lines above are relative momenta,. Even if I were to consider this as a conservation of momenta in a different frame, we can see that it is in complete generalization. This is not written in the frame of particle 2 at least by using a Galilean transformation because $\vec{p}_{2}$ and $\vec{p'}_{2}$ are generally different.

Then it writes the conservation of momentum and energy equation as follows.

$$\vec{p_{1}}+\vec{p_{2}}= \vec{p'_{1}}+\vec{p'_{2}}$$

$$\vec{p'_{1}}-\vec{p'_{2}}= |\vec{p_{1}}-\vec{p_{2}}|\hat{\Omega(b)}$$

The first equation makes sense; the total momentum before and after. But I am confused at the energy conservation equation. It appears to be equating the magnitude of the **relative** momentum before, equivalent to setting the kinetic energy before and after of the relative momentum, but I don't understand why it is being applied to the relative momentum and how this is consistent with the conservation of momentum equation. I believe I am confused about how the relative momentum is being considered.

Can these two equations be explained? How is the second energy equation sound given that it is using relative momentum?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.